# git rebase -x ("exec") with Magit?

Tags: magit, git

Is it possible to use the "exec" mechanism when rebasing with magit?

From the git rebase man page:

```
   -x <cmd>, --exec <cmd>
       Append "exec <cmd>" after each line creating a commit in the final history. <cmd> will be interpreted as one or more shell commands.
```

For example, verifying that tests pass when rebasing the manual command might be:

```
git rebase -x "make test"
```

Note: I'm *not* interested in manually specifying an individual "x" exec in an interactive rebase.  I would like the specified command run after each commit when rebasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `git rebase --exec` isn't currently supported, but adding `--exec` to the rebase popup should work:

```
(magit-define-popup-option 'magit-rebase-popup
  ?x "Exec command" "--exec=" #'read-shell-command)
```